# Stop Powershell script pane tab rows reordering

Tags: powershell, tabs

In Powershell ISE with several files open the tabs spill over to a second row. Ctrl-[Shift-]tab will switch between the files open, or the mouse can be used to select a different file. When a tab on the top row is selected the whole row of tabs in the PowerShell script pane is moved to the bottom. When switching between files this UI change can be nauseating.

How can I change the configuration of the PowerShell IDE so that the tabs in the script pane do not move when a different file is selected?

```
Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 4.0
```

Comment: I doubt you'll ever be able to change this behaviour, maybe just have less files open instead. You might want to take a look at PowerGUI (http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/m/bits) which is free. Its tab control might behave differently.

Comment: I assume you mean the PowerShell *ISE*.  Which version of PowerShell are you running?  The ISE changed slightly with each version.

Comment: I have found a workaround. Open one PowerShell Tab per file (Ctrl-T) then alt-tab works to change between PowerShell tabs. If multiple files are open in a single PowerShell Tab then alt-tab can be used to rotate focus, and Ctrl-D can be used to change focus to the Console, and then alt-tab rotates between PowerShell tabs. Ctrl-I returns focus to the script plane to allow switching between open files (if multiple files are open). This is not ideal.. but it feels far better than watching the rows constantly flicking up and down.

Comment: @Kev Third part software can't be installed on Windows servers. I did look at PowerShell editors but can't even download the software here.